# Android - display toast message in multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, toast

I have two `fragments` (making using of a `ViewPager`).
I would like to show a `toast` message in each of these `fragments` (separately).

Currently, when displaying the `toast` messages, they all appear on the "first" `fragment`.
Can someone point me in the right direction please.

I will post the necessary/applicable code on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implements `View.OnPageChangeListener` from your own `ViewPager` and show the `Toast` when the `onPageSelected` is fired